# Angular Routing not working with Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I am building a project in Django and Angular. I have out the following code to provide routing after including/loading the angular routing library in my main html page.

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('scrumboard.demo')
    .config (['$routeProvider', config])
    .run(['$http',run]);

function config($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when ('/', {
            templateUrl: '/static/html/scrumboard.html',
            controller: 'ScrumboardController',
        })

        .when ('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/static/html/login.html'
        })
        .otherwise('/');
}

function run($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
})();
```

My urls.py looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'$', ensure_csrf_cookie(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"))),
path(r'scrumboard/', include('scrumboard.urls')),
path(r'auth_api/', include('auth_api.urls')),
]
```

and I have included following in the settings.py

```
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =(
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
```

Yet, when I load localhost:8000/login  then no page gets loaded but when I load localhost:8000/static/html/login.html then the page loads correctly. It seems angular routing is not working correctly.

Comment: In my main html page I have included code as this >>> `<body ng-app="scrumboard.demo">
        <ng-view></ng-view>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="{% static "js/scrumboard.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/scrumboard.config.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/card.directive.js" %}"></script>

    </body>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the {% verbatim %} tag ? For more details you can check -http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template-sharing.html

Comment: I tried it with  {% verbatim %}  {% endverbatim %} surrounding the <ng-view></ng-view>, but did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving:

```
url(r'$', ensure_csrf_cookie(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html")))
```

To the bottom of your url pattern list.